# Split view controller question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I just started looking at split view controllers and i have some questions

- How can I design the interface for each root view? For example you press 'root1' and the detailed view contains a label and a sound volume, you press 'root2' and the detailed view contains 2 labels and 2 sound volumes.
- Are there any tutorials out there that would help me out?

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the basic tutorial first, it will teach you how to create an iPad project that uses the `UISplitViewController` to display content in 2 separate panes.you could also download the source code from the tutorial post.

[iPad Programming Tutorial – Hello World](http://doronkatz.com/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world)

[iPad Programming](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad.pdf)